# Submit button is not working when appending HTML form with jQuery

Tags: http, jquery

I have two HTML forms. First one is **searchForm** and second one is **searchFormSPECIAL**.

The difference is that **searchForm** gets printed initially in the HTML, while **searchFormSPECIAL** is appended by jQuery when user click button **oooo**.

I also set up two submit listeners *$("#searchForm").submit(function(event)* and *$("#searchFormSpecial").submit(function(event)*. First one is working, second one is not.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#test_only").click(function () {
            $('body').append(commentFormSPECIAL());
        });

        function commentFormSPECIAL() {
            var comment_form_html = '<form action="/comment" id="searchFormSPECIAL">\
            <input type="text" name="r" placeholder="Topic ID" />\
            <input type="text" name="c" placeholder="Comment ..." />\
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />\
            </form>'

            return comment_form_html;
        //return "";
      }

      $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
            /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Hey you are submitting searchForm")
        });

      $('#searchFormSPECIAL').submit(function(event){
        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Hey you are submitting searchFormSPECIAL");
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form action="/new" id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Topic..." />
            <input type="text" name="l" placeholder="http://www.google.com" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Topic" />
        </form>

        <button id="test_only">ooooo</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that jQuery is not recognizing appended form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should bind the click event when the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed by the browser.
Try to put your code in [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#test_only").click(function () {
              $('body').append(commentFormSPECIAL());
          });

          function commentFormSPECIAL() {
              var comment_form_html = '<form action="/comment" id="searchFormSPECIAL">\
              <input type="text" name="r" placeholder="Topic ID" />\
              <input type="text" name="c" placeholder="Comment ..." />\
              <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />\
              </form>'

              return comment_form_html;
              //return "";
          }

          $("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
              /* stop form from submitting normally */
              event.preventDefault();
              alert("Hey you are submitting searchForm")
           });

          $(document).on('submit', '#searchFormSPECIAL', function (event) {
          /* stop form from submitting normally */
              event.preventDefault();
              alert("Hey you are submitting searchFormSPECIAL");
          });
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form action="/new" id="searchForm">
            <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Topic..." />
            <input type="text" name="l" placeholder="http://www.google.com" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Topic" />
        </form>

        <button id="test_only">ooooo</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to bind to the searchFormSPECIAL submit action before the form has actually been created.

Try changing

```
$('#searchFormSPECIAL').submit(function(event){
```

to

```
$('#searchFormSPECIAL').on("submit", function(event){
```

Comment: [As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use **.on()** to attach event handlers.](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working either. It is still using HTML submit instead of what jQuery submit.

Comment: It seems like jQuery can't recognize #searchFormSPECIAL. I tried testing it with $('#searchFormSPECIAL').on("click", alert("Hello!")) and nothing happens when I click.